# Screen freezing while fast traveling in Skyrim. How do I stop it?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I just finished the quest Battle for Whiterun. I listened to the Jarl's speech and started the quest, Reunification of Skyrim. I am to report to General Tallius, but every time I try to fast travel to Solitude the game freezes. No sound. No movement of the screen whatsoever. No Xbox guide. I don't have any add-ons so I don't think its a corrupted file. I don't know what to do.

Comment: try disabling autosave and then fast traveling see if that helps.  Also, have you tried fast traveling to any other place?

Comment: I agree that you should try what @lI suggested. I would also try exiting Whiterun on foot, then trying to fast travel.

Answer (score -1):

When I had that problem what I did was look up to see what could be done about that and what I found is that for some reason when auto saves our present it stops the game from loading on the console so what google suggested is that you clear out your auto saves and that stops freezing from happening so give it a try and it should stop the problem.

Here's what you can do: You can type in the statement: Sky Rim Won't Load on the Google Bar and it should bring up answers to that problem.

Comment: This seems like a possible solution. It would help if you added a link to wherever you found this advice.

Comment: Well that should be a bit more helpful at least I hope so.

Comment: Telling people how to Google something is incredibly *unhelpful*.